# switch case working in second long press but not on first long press

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

I am trying to capture the long click event and displaying a alert box of items inside the list view.. which I am doing using switch case... which was working fine.

Issue:

when I long press the items inside the listview at `first long press` no alert box is displayed but if I do the same `second time` alert box is displayed.. I couldn't understand the behaviour...

Can experts help me with this also please let me know where I am doing wrong and also correct me so that at first long press I need to get the alert box.

Code:

```
Listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Inside listview long click");   


                    final ViewHolder myviewholder3=new ViewHolder();
                    myviewholder3.cb=(CheckBox) arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    myviewholder3.view1=(Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.button1); 

                    System.out.println(arg1.getId());
                    System.out.println("cb"+R.id.checkBox1);
                    System.out.println(arg1.getId());
                    System.out.println("butt"+R.id.button1);
                    switch(arg1.getId()){

                    case R.id.checkBox1:
                    myviewholder3.cb.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AlertDialog.Builder Alert1=new AlertDialog.Builder(sm.this);

                            StockAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
                            Alert1.show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                    case R.id.button1:
                    myviewholder3.view1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AlertDialog.Builder ViewDetailAlert=new AlertDialog.Builder(sm.this);

                            Alert2.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
                            Alert2.show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;

            default:
                System.out.println("No Selection");
                    }
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: The holder listener is set only after the first long click on the list item.

Comment: @user3249477 ok thanks for your response... but how can I overcome this...

Comment: you need to register the listeners for the holders when they are created. Tip: Inside the adapter's `getView`.

Comment: @user3249477 Actually I am using cursor adapter can I write that in bindview

Comment: You should do that in `newView`.

Comment: @user3249477 actually I wrote in `bindview` and its working.. is it the correct way... Thanks for your response..

Comment: If that works for you sure, no problem. However, now everytime you set data to a list item, you re-create the listeners. If you were to set them at `newView` you would need to create only N listeners, N being the max visible items at a single given time.

Comment: @user3249477 can you please clarify me one more query... to get a longpress event of a item in list view it is not necessary to write in the longpress event of the listview.. thanks

Comment: @user3249477 ok I got your point... bind view will loop till number of items in the list view.. so not suggested in `bind view`.. am I correct? if yes I am using `view holder` will that reduce the impact.. of creating many times... thanks

Comment: You're missing the point. Bindview is called when a new item becomes visible to the user. Thus every time an item becomes visible you create a **new listener**, which could have been done when the item view was created. Anyways your question has been answered, so if you're still unsure about this, ask another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because of you are registering `onLongClickListener` for your Views inside `onItemLongClick`, so at first time when you are Long clicking your ListView Items , it just register onLongClickListener for your Views, then at second time when you are long Clicking, the LongClick of your Items's View will work as expected . try Registering listeners for your Views of ListView inside of the getView().

Comment: thanks for your response... but I couldn't understand can you please elobarate more?

Comment: but how can I overcome... as items are present inside list view I can't declare them outside

Comment: you can register listeners for your ListView ,views inside of getView().

Comment: Actually I am using `cursor adapter` can I write that in `bindview`

Comment: @Siva: yes you can but if you can, make a custom class which extends Cursor Adapter to give you more control over your adapter.

Comment: I wrote in `bindview` and its working... thanks.. can you please clarify me one more query... to get a `longpress` event of a item in list view it is not necessary to write in the longpress event of the listview.. thanks